# Stochastic Processes Solution manuals.

Tags: probability, soft-question, stochastic-processes, book-recommendation, online-resources

Does anyone have a link or a pdf stash of solution manuals for stochastic processes ebooks? 
I am doing a self-study on this course and I can't seem to find any solution manual online to cross-check my solutions with.

Any author or volume or version is ok with me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Full solutions to all exercises in *Brownian Motion - An Introduction to Stochastic Processes* by René Schilling & Lothar Partzsch are available on [this webpage](http://motapa.de/brownian_motion/index.shtml).

Comment: Adding to Sez's input, one should note that anything written by Schilling is very solid - he has another text on measure theory that is a great read.

Comment: @ArbiasHashani Yeah, I agree with you. I like this book (on Brownian motion) pretty much :)

Answer (score 0):

The text book we are currently using is Introduction to Probability Models by Sheldon M. Ross. It has the 10 edition solution manual online. However, I encourage you buy the solution manual from google e-book or any other source. It is less than 10 dollar.